# Case expression in where clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I have a pull some data out of Oracle tables based on some condition.

If a person with JobFunctionCode = 'ADMIN' then when he resign the notified_termination_date populate and then his data should be picked up.

The person from other JobFunctionCode like Manager, Finance etc when they resign the accepted_termination_date populates then their data should be picked up.

So pull out data based on these conditions I wrote a case statement in my `WHERE` clause, but its giving missing parenthesis error. This SQL is a scheduled run so I have set the termination dates to `sysdate` and this will run on a daily basis.

```
select ppos.person_id, paam.position_id, pjf.job_function_code 
from 
    per_all_assignments_m paam, per_periods_of_service ppos, per_jobs_f pjf
    where
    case
        when    pjf.job_function_code = 'ADMIN' then (TO_CHAR(ppos.notified_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
        else    (TO_CHAR(ppos.accepted_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    end
    and paam.person_id = ppos.person_id
    and paam.job_id = pjf.job_id
    and paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
    and TO_CHAR(paam.effective_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '4712-12-31'
    and TO_CHAR(pjf.effective_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '4712-12-31'
```

Also, there can be the condition when Person from both JobFunctionCode terminates then both person data should be pulled out, so I don't think in this case a `CASE` expression can be used.

Please let me know how to write the logic here?

Comment: So , basically you need to fetch data if admin resigns on notified_termination_date  and other jobFunctionCode resigns on accepted_termination_date. Is it the requirement?

Comment: Yes, and also if Person A with JobFunctionCode 'ADMIN' and Person B with JobFunctionCode 'MANAGER' resign on same day then both of these Person's data should come, some kind of OR logic..might be..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause should be:

```
where
(
    (pjf.job_function_code = 'ADMIN' and TO_CHAR(ppos.notified_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    or (pjf.job_function_code <> 'ADMIN' and TO_CHAR(ppos.accepted_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
)
and <rest of clauses>
```

I havent looked at the rest of it, whether the TO-CHAR is required, etc, but this will fix your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
((case 
   when pjf.job_function_code = 'ADMIN'
       case 
          when (TO_CHAR(ppos.notified_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) then 'Y'
          else 'N'
       end
   else 
      case  
         when (TO_CHAR(ppos.accepted_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) then 'Y'
         else 'N'
      end
end )='Y'  
or exists (select * from <<tablename>> pjf.job_function_code = 'ADMIN' 
and (TO_CHAR(ppos.notified_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = (TO_CHAR(ppos.accepted_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))));
```

P.S: Just check the brackets closure, and write the query in exists clause as per your table design

Answer (score 1):

In `where` clause case when is not allowed, you can write your condition below way

```
where       
   ( pjf.job_function_code = 'ADMIN' AND 
  (TO_CHAR(ppos.notified_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    Or    (TO_CHAR(ppos.accepted_termination_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
    )
and paam.person_id = ppos.person_id
and paam.job_id = pjf.job_id
and paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
and TO_CHAR(paam.effective_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '4712-12-31'
and TO_CHAR(pjf.effective_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '4712-12-31'
```